# sql injection when server doubles apostrophe

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand when there's no protection(doubling ' to '') we can simply use

```
'or'1=1--
```

but how do I accomplish this when the server doubles the '? From my research it appears we use the \ but I'm still confused how.

I've tried:

```
\'or\'1=1--
```

But I get a syntax error. What am I misunderstanding? Thank you

Comment: what are you asking ?

Comment: Please add your complete code that you are testing over it. -HTH ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid SQL injection, the best practice is to avoid functions that directly insert queries to the database (such as `mysqli_query()`.  Instead, stored procedures and prepared statements can provide a layer of protection against SQL injection. See [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) on w3schools and [stored procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx) on MySQLTutorial.

However, you can fix your issue with inserting apostrophes (' and ") using simply the PHP functions `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `htmlspecialchars()` on all inserted data.  This method is by no means secure, but will allow data to be inserted with these characters and -- who knows -- stop a very remedial hacker.